# Looping through All collections in VBA

Tags: vba, collections, excel

I have a program where I create several different collections in VBA.  After the program completes, I need to delete the records in each collection.  I have been able to delete the collections statically with the following code:

```
Sub Empty_Collections()
    Dim Count As Integer
    Dim i As Long

    Count = Managers.Count
    For i = 1 To Count
         Managers.Remove (Managers.Count)
    Next i

    Count = FS.Count
    For i = 1 To Count
         FS.Remove (FS.Count)
    Next i

    Count = Staff.Count
    For i = 1 To Count
         Staff.Remove (Staff.Count)
    Next i

    Count = Clusters.Count

    For i = 1 To Count
         Clusters.Remove (Clusters.Count)
    Next i

End Sub
```

However, as I may add additional Collections in the future, is it possible to have code similar to this:

```
Dim Item As Collection
Dim Count As Integer
Dim i As Long

For Each Item In Worksheets
    Count = Item.Count

    For i = 1 To Count
         Item.Remove (Item.Count)
    Next i

Next
```

Comment: Much easier just to do (eg) `Set Managers = New Collection`

Comment: If you want to be able to track all of your collections then you can always put them in a collection.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand what you are doing, there should be no need to clean up when your program completes unless you have circular references. The garbage collector ought to take care of that for you.

Comment: Another way of doing what Tim says in the first comment: `Set Managers = Nothing`

Answer (score 0):

While I hesitate to create globals like this, here is a possible solution:

In the `ThisWorkbook` Excel Object, add the following:

```
Private pCollections As Collection
Public Property Get Collections() As Collection
    If pCollections Is Nothing Then: Set pCollections = New Collection
    Set Collections = pCollections
End Property
Public Property Set Collections(Value As Collection)
    Set pCollections = Value
End Property

Public Sub AddCollection(Name As String)
    Dim Coll As New Collection
    Me.Collections.Add Coll, Name
End Sub

Public Sub EmptyCollections()
    Dim Coll As Collection
    For Each Coll In Me.Collections
        EmptyCollection Coll
    Next Coll
End Sub

Private Sub EmptyCollection(ByRef Coll As Collection)
    Do While Coll.Count > 0
        ' Remove items from the end of the collection
        Coll.Remove Coll.Count
    Loop
End Sub
```

Then add and work with collections as follows:

```
' Add collections
' (without helper)
Dim Managers As New Collection
ThisWorkbook.Collections.Add Managers, "Managers"

' (with helper)
ThisWorkbook.AddCollection "FS"
ThisWorkbook.AddCollection "Staff"
ThisWorkbook.AddCollection "Clusters"

' Add items to collection
' (access collection via named key for ease-of-use)
ThisWorkbook.Collections("Managers").Add "Alice"
ThisWorkbook.Collections("Managers").Add "Bob"

' (or original reference if desired
Managers.Add "Carl"

Debug.Print Managers.Count ' => 3
Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Collections("Managers").Count ' => 3

' Add collection later
ThisWorkbook.AddCollection "FutureCollection"

' Empty all collections
ThisWorkbook.EmptyCollections
```

This may be a little more complex than what you are looking for, but it has the advantage of adding collections to a central location so that they can all be emptied later.